# Where does the 'set as wallpaper' feature save your picture in Gingerbread (2.3)?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, file-system, wallpaper

I had an image from a website which I set as my background inside the browser. I am wondering now where I can find the image in the file system, because I can't find it online anymore. I already checked all the obvious folders including Downloads, but did not find it there. In fact there is an answer for a similar question on this forum, but that is for Ice Cream Sandwich (ICS) and I am on Gingerbread, which is why that answer did not help me.

Answer (score 1):

`/data/data/com.android.settings/files/wallpaper`. It's a PNG file and appears to be uncompressed due to the size.

Comment: how do you access that? Does it require root privilates?

Answer (score 1):

I have just developed an app that can save your current wallpaper to SD, share it, ect. Furthermore it automatically saves a copy of each wallpaper you set, so you will get a history of all the wallpapers you have been using.
My app is called [Wallpaper Saver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.alroe.apps.WallpaperSaverFree), can be downloaded from Google Play and is Free!

When using Wallpaper Saver files are stored in `/Android/data/dk.alroe.apps.WallpaperSaverFree/files/wallpapers`. You can see the path inside settings as well. It can also sync your wallpapers with Dropbox

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://www.droidiser.com/2013/08/android-wallpaper-location-how-to-extract.html):

> ### Location of Current wallpaper:
>
> - For Android 4.0 and below: Once in /,
>
>   - go to /data/data/com.android.settings/files.
> - Find a file named wallpaper in that folder and copy it to any location you want. Rename the copied file to anything.jpg or anything.png to open it as a normal image file.

This requires root.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies.